# Image classification with Keras: "expected activation_1 to have shape (2,) but got array with (1,)"

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm training an image classifier to distinguish cats and dogs, from the Kaggle set.

Here's my relevant code:

```
FINAL_ACTIVATION = "softmax"
OPTIMIZER = keras.optimizers.Adamax()
STRIDES = (2, 2)
DROPOUT = 0.5

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = INPUT_SHAPE))
model.add(keras.layers.ELU())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = STRIDES))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(keras.layers.ELU())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = STRIDES))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(keras.layers.ELU())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = STRIDES))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(keras.layers.ELU())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = STRIDES))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(keras.layers.ELU())
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))

model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(keras.layers.ELU())
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation(FINAL_ACTIVATION))

model.compile(
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer = OPTIMIZER,
    metrics = ["accuracy"]
)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
)

model.summary()

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = x_train.shape[0] // BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs = EPOCHS
)
```

Due to the large number of training files, there's no testing set. However, when I try to train this network I get the error "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)." What am I doing wrong here?

Convolutional neural networks are still a little bit of black magic to me, so I may be making some beginner mistakes here. I figure I probably am.

Here's my model:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 98, 98, 32)        896
_________________________________________________________________
elu_1 (ELU)                  (None, 98, 98, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 49, 49, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 47, 47, 64)        18496
_________________________________________________________________
elu_2 (ELU)                  (None, 47, 47, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 23, 23, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 21, 21, 128)       73856
_________________________________________________________________
elu_3 (ELU)                  (None, 21, 21, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 10, 10, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 128)         147584
_________________________________________________________________
elu_4 (ELU)                  (None, 8, 8, 128)         0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 128)         0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 2048)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100)               204900
_________________________________________________________________
elu_5 (ELU)                  (None, 100)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 50)                5050
_________________________________________________________________
elu_6 (ELU)                  (None, 50)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 102
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 2)                 0
=================================================================
Total params: 450,884
Trainable params: 450,884
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: This error says the network expects your target value is of shape `(batch_size,2)`, but your actual target value is of shape `(batch_size,1)`. So check your target values, i.e. `y` values in the generator.

Comment: Not having a test set is just a big mistake.

Answer (score 1):

> Due to the large number of training files, there's no testing set.

While this is not your question, I feel this should be addressed: I understand there are some groups following a very different approach and not keeping valid/test sets, but this sounds very unorthodox and uncertain to me. Personally, I rarely see articles without test tests or some kind of post-train validation.

Test sets are useful because they are empirical evidence that your model is working for unseen samples. Using them + statistical significance/confidence tests, you can then assert with statistical basis that your model is not only a very complicated if-else machine.

The bottom line is that if you are new to the area, you shouldn't abide to risky strategies like this.

**Regarding your problem:** what's `y_train.shape`? I believe you are flowing sparse labels (`[1., 0., 1., 2., 3., ..., 4.]`) instead of one-hot encoded ones:

```py
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 0.]]
```

Where `argmax(x, axis=1)` gives you the true class index.

**How to solve it:**

Replace `loss="categorical_crossentropy"` by `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. This is memory efficient, but requires that each sample to be associated with a **single** label.

OR

One-hot encode `y_train` before passing it to `ImageDataGenerator#flow`:

```py
from keras.utils import to_categorical

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(...)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, ...)
...
```

This is more memory consuming, but allows a single sample to be associated with more than a single label:

```py
[[1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 0. 1.]]
```